# Why is django not sending my email and instead giving me an error?

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to get django to send an email but I get as a return in my terminal the print from my else that says there was a problem and it wasn't sent. Why is this happening?

This is the code with the email:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from . import views

def constancia_email(email):

   subject, from_email, to = 'Constancia Monotributo', 'bosi@outlook.es', email
   text_content = 'Hi, this is your pfd.'
   html_content = '<p><strong>Hi!</strong></p> <p>This is your pdf</p>'
   
   msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
   attachment = open('constancia.pdf', 'rb')
   msg.attach('constancia.pdf', attachment.read(), 'text/pdf')
   msg.content_subtype = 'html'
   msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
   msg.send()
```

This is the view part with the email:

```
#send email
               constancia_email(email)

               if constancia_email == True:
                   print("Sus datos fueron enviados correctamente, en un máximo de 2 hs. estarás recibiendo tu constancia por email.")
               else:
                   print("No hemos podido procesar su solicitud, por favor reintente nuevamente más tarde.")
```

I added this to my settings because I was getting an error but I'm not sure if this helps because I just get the email in my console but it still isn't sent:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Exactly what error is it printing?

Comment: you need to set more of the `EMAIL_` values in your settings (ie smtp server and credentials not just the backend)

Answer (score 1):

:). Everything works as expected, doesn't it? The email console backend is not sending emails anywhere, it just displays them in the console.

PS: If you feel that you are ready to send your emails to outside world, use EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'